# Can an if statement be a variable?

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, if-statement, conditional-statements

Apologies for the title, I don't know the terminology for what I am trying to do.

I have a function that has a series of nested loops, that runs a huge amount of times.  The loops have many conditions as to whether they continue, or start over.

Occasionally, this function is called such that it needs to meet certain conditions that are *rare*.  However, to check for them, I need to add even more if statements into my code.

Here is an example of what I am talking about, some of the looping in my function:

```
while 1:

    for node in currset:

        for (sum1, weight1, l1, r1) in pathdict[(0, node)]:  
            if sum1 & sum != sum1 or r1 == left or r1 == right or l1 == left:
                continue

            if level < connectright:
                if l1 == right:
                    continue
            elif l1 != right:
                    continue

            for (sum2, weight2, l2, r2) in pathdict[(level, r1)]:
                if sum2&sum != sum2:
                    continue
                if l2 != left or l2 == right:
                    continue
                andsum = sum1&sum2

                if andsum != r1:
                    continue
```

Now, what do I do if I have a special case where many of these conditions no longer apply?  The way I see it now, I can either 1.)write an entirely new function, 2.)rewrite the entire block of code and put it after another if statement, 3.)add a series of even more conditions, or 4.)write a function that checks my conditions at a given step.

The first 2 options seem bulky but at least my code would go fast.  The 3rd seems horrible because the code becomes hard to read, and it slows down.  And the 4th, I am unsure but it seems like calling these functions so many times would slow down my loops.

So my question is, is there some way that I can write "conditional if statements", where depending on the variables passed to the function, I could do something like:

```
if variable_passed == thing#1:
     my_if_statement = (if level < connectright:  continue)
else:
     my_if_statement = (if level > connectright:  continue)
```

This way I could easily change my conditions at the start of the function, before I begin looping.

Comment: Can be done. Try it out yourself and then ask a new question if required.

Comment: You cannot call continue or break outside of the loop (ie in functions)

Comment: The fourth is the cleanest.  It does come with a performance hit.  But the performance hit seldom matters in practice.  As the standard optimization advice goes, 1. Don't. 2. (experts only) Don't yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create lists of functions that all take the same arguments and calculate the condition using a subset of the arguments.

It looks a little much to me unless you have a lot, or are generating the conditions.

An example:

```
outer = [  # lambda parameters are all that could be used in any expression at point of call
            (lambda sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright:
                sum1 & sum != sum1 or r1 == left or r1 == right or l1 == left),
            (lambda sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright:
                level < connectright),
            (lambda sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright: 
                l1 != right),
        # ... add extra outer loop conditions as necessary
        ]
inner1 = [  # lambda parameters are all that could be used in any expression at point of call
            (lambda sum2, weight2, l2, r2, sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright: 
                sum2&sum != sum2),
            (lambda sum2, weight2, l2, r2, sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright: 
                l2 != left or l2 == right),
        # ... add extra inner loop conditions as necessary
        ]
inner2 = [  # lambda parameters are all that could be used in any expression at point of call
            (lambda andsum, sum2, weight2, l2, r2, sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright: 
                andsum != r1),
        # ... add extra inner loop #2 conditions as necessary
        ]

while True:
    for node in currset:
        for (sum1, weight1, l1, r1) in pathdict[(0, node)]:  
            if any(f(sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright)
                    for f in outer):
                continue
            for (sum2, weight2, l2, r2) in pathdict[(level, r1)]:
                if any(f(sum2, weight2, l2, r2, sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright)
                        for f in inner1):
                    continue
                andsum = sum1&sum2
                if any(f(andsum, sum2, weight2, l2, r2, sum, sum1, weight1, l1, r1, left, right, level, connectright)
                        for f in inner2):
                    continue
```